# Some help with a crosstab query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE game
AS
  SELECT team_name, match_id, sections_won
  FROM ( VALUES
    ( 'Team A', 6  , 4 ),
    ( 'Team B', 6  , 1 ),
    ( 'Team A', 19 , 4 ),
    ( 'Team A', 8  , 4 ),
    ( 'Team B', 19 , 1 ),
    ( 'Team B', 8  , 1 ),
    ( 'Team A', 7  , 4 ),
    ( 'Team B', 7  , 1 )
  ) AS t(team_name, match_id, sections_won);
```

It's for a game, so teams compete in matches.  The match has a possible 5 points and in these examples 1 team is winning 4 of the 5 sections

I'd like to pivot this into a scoreboard where the report looks like this:

```
Name    Match 6 Match 7 Match 8 Match 19
Team A  4       4       4       4
Team B  1       1       1       1
```

I've done this kind of thing before but I can't get this one to work for some reason.

The query looks a little like this.  I tried to simplify for examples sake.

```
select *
from crosstab(
  $$
    select game.team_name::text, game.match_id, sum(game.rank)::int4
    from game
    where rank = 1 -- i only want the sections the team won, then sum above.
    group by 1,2
 $$
  ) as ct("Team" text, "Match 6" int4 ,"Match 7" int4 ,"Match 8" int4 ,"Match 19" int4)
;
```

The resulting data set looks like this though, which I don't get:

```
Name    Match 6 Match 7 Match 8 Match 19
team a  4       null    null    null     
team b  1       null    null    null   
team a  4       4       null    null
team b  1       1       null    null
team a  4       null    null    null   
team b  1       null    null    null
```

Any thoughts?  I've spent several hours on this puppy so far.  Driving me nuts!  :)

Comment: are sections_won and rank the same?

Comment: Thanks for the edit Evan!  I should have done that probably.

Comment: oh wow!  So adding the order by did work! @McNets I'm not sure I fully understand why though?

Comment: @EvanCarroll answer is crystal clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `GROUP BY` in a pivot... And, if you put that `WHERE` clause in there you're filtering out stuff you need.

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
  $$
    SELECT game.team_name::text, game.match_id, game.sections_won
    FROM game
    ORDER by 1,2
 $$
  ) as ct("Team" text, "Match 6" int4 ,"Match 7" int4 ,"Match 8" int4 ,"Match 19" int4)
;

  Team  | Match 6 | Match 7 | Match 8 | Match 19 
--------+---------+---------+---------+----------
 Team A |       4 |       4 |       4 |        4
 Team B |       1 |       1 |       1 |        1
(2 rows)
```

As to why you need the `ORDER BY`, from [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html)

> In practice the SQL query should always specify ORDER BY 1,2 to ensure that the input rows are properly ordered, that is, values with the same row_name are brought together and correctly ordered within the row. Notice that crosstab itself does not pay any attention to the second column of the query result; it's just there to be ordered by, to control the order in which the third-column values appear across the page.